# Why am I getting error at line 1 on Create Table

Tags: mysql, create-table

First time working with MySQL. Using MySQL Workbench with a new instance installed on my Windows 10 desktop. I've created a test test db/schema, and now trying to create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE kcplusers (
'user_barcode' varchar(255),
'first_name' varchar(255),
'middle_name' varchar(255),
'last_name' varchar(255),
'address_street' varchar(500),
'city_state' varchar(500),
'zip' varchar(100),
'user_profile' varchar(500),
'birth_date' DATE
);
```

Workbench shows a red x at line 1 and red slashes under the open-parenth (

I get the error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_barcode' varchar(255),  'first_name' varchar(255),      'middle_name' varc' at line 2

What am I missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

Don't use single quotes `'` for the fields names, use backticks ` or nothing at all:

```
CREATE TABLE kcplusers (
`user_barcode` varchar(255),
`first_name` varchar(255),
`middle_name` varchar(255),
`last_name` varchar(255),
`address_street` varchar(500),
`city_state` varchar(500),
`zip` varchar(100),
`user_profile` varchar(500),
`birth_date` DATE
);
```

Comment: "backticks"! I was searching for that term! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, ibu and Pete! I thought I had tried it at one point without any quotes or backticks. But removing them this time worked!

Answer (score 1):

You're using apostrophes around the column names - they should be removed in this case. 
If you must specify certain characters in a column name you can use ascii cd 96 shown as ` - usually just to the left of the number "1" on your keyboard.
But to keep it simple as you're starting out - just remove the apostrophes.
And let us know how it turns out (good or bad)
Cheers!